# NHibernate type does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lucene.net

I'm upgrading a solution I create about 4 years on 3.3.2.4000 to 4.0.4.4000. When I try to bring it up I get the following error:

```
{"Method 'Set' in type 'iSeguro.Data.Mappings.EmpresaBridge' from assembly 'iSeguro.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.":"iSeguro.Data.Mappings.EmpresaBridge"}
```

The type definition is as follows:

```
public class EmpresaBridge : IFieldBridge
{
    public void Set(string name, object value, Document document, Field.Store store, Field.Index index, float? boost)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;
        if (value != null) data = ((Empresa)value).Nombre;
        document.Add(new Field(name, data, store, index));
    }
}
```

The mapping type:

```
public partial class ValoracionSearchMap : DocumentMap<Valoracion>
{
    public ValoracionSearchMap()
    {
        Name("Valoracion");
        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.Asunto).Store().No().Index().Tokenized().Boost(4);
        Map(c => c.Descripcion).Store().No().Index().Tokenized();
        Map(c => c.Publicar).Store().Yes().Index().Tokenized();

        Map(c => c.Creador).Store().Yes().Index().Tokenized();
        FieldBridge(c => c.Creador).Custom<UsuarioBridge>();

        Map(c => c.Empresa).Store().Yes().Index().Tokenized();
        FieldBridge(c => c.Empresa).Custom<EmpresaBridge>();

        Map(c => c.Producto).Store().Yes().Index().Tokenized();
        FieldBridge(c => c.Producto).Custom<ProductoBridge>();
    }
}
```

I've been out of the game for a while and just have no idea what the error is relating. This is suppose to hook objects with lucene.net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your dll versions. This might be an old reference to the project that implements IFieldBridge.

1. Remeve references to your own projects under Project > References
2. Close the solution and delete all 'bin' and 'obj' folders in your project folders
3. Rebuild all projects